# Delphi object without Create?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have downloaded [Open Source SynTaskDialog unit for XP,Vista,Seven](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/05/Open-Source-SynTaskDialog-unit-for-XP,Vista,Seven)
and have noticed something I didn't know before.

The `TTaskDialog` is declared (for Delphi7. for newer version it is defined a s `record`) as:

```
TTaskDialog = object
  Title: string;
  Inst: string;
  ...
  function Execute...
end;
```

and was amazed to see the usage is:

```
var Task: TTaskDialog;
Task.Inst := 'Saving application settings';
Task.Execute(...);
```

There is no `Task := TTaskDialog.Create`.

I made also a small test:

```
type
  TTest = object
    Caption: string;
    procedure Execute;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t: TTest;
begin
  // t := TTest.Create; // there is no Create method
  t.Caption := 'Hello';
  t.Execute;
end;
```

And it also works without issues.

if I change the declaration to `TTest = class`, I must instantiate the object or else I get an AV on forms destruction.

**How** and **Why** does it work? Is it common and safe to use such "class" without any instanciation?. is it a class or is it something like modern Delphi records?

Please help me to shade some light on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not read the documentation? It's a legacy Turbo Pascal object, should not be used today. Replaced by enhanced records. It is documented. You don't need to be amazed.

Comment: Of course, you might have to wait a little until Emba's web server is back online .......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, "should not be used today" - noticed the Delphi 7 tag? noticed that it is *used* in the  SynTaskDialog? I haven't found my answers in the docs, sorry. and I'm a bit old and senile to remember  Turbo Pascal objects... I can be amazed over and over again for not remembering :)

Comment: Shouldn't be used in D7 either really. I'm amazed at you not looking in the documentation. Do you know how to search for documentation?

Comment: Never mind. the duplicate was a great help to me. which BTW, could be answered also by "looking in the docs"...

Comment: Actually, I think I'm going to use this a lot from now on in our Delphi 7 application. As I can see, it has great benefits over records. Emba should not have break it on newer Delphi versions.

Comment: What benefits over enhanced records?

Comment: I'm referring to old Delphi versions without enhanced records.

Comment: You made a comment about newer versions. That's what I referred to. Objects are nice when you want automatic storage. For instance for performance. But only for quite simple types. Don't try inheritance with them!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and those very dialogs he downloaded out of mORMot project, which is both very D7-centric and very performance-centric :-D

Comment: Dialogs aren't performance sensitive.